# strptime python error

Tags: python, datetime, flask

Tengo el siguiente string

```
from datetime import date, time, timezone, timedelta, datetime

fechaLiquidacion='2020-01-01'
```

Y quiero formatearla a datetime para poder hacer una consulta a la base de datos. Intente utlizando la siguiente funcion:

```
Fecha=datetime.strptime(fechaLiquidacion, "%Y %m %d")
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error, leyendo la documentacion del modulo datetime no encuentro errores.

```
time data '2020-01-01' does not match format '%Y %m %d'
```

Incluso probe de la siguiente manera

```
 datetime.strptime(fechaLiquidacion, '%Y/%m/%d',)
```

Pero me tira el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el formato "%Y %m %d" dijistes que año, mes y dia están separados por blancos.

La fecha que estas pasando está separada con guiones.

Cambia el formato a '%Y-%m-%d'

```
from datetime import date, time, timezone, timedelta, datetime

fechaLiquidacion='2020-01-01'
Fecha=datetime.strptime(fechaLiquidacion, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(Fecha)
```

produce

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

**Edit**
Para descartar la hora,

```
print(Fecha.__str__()[:10])
```

Comment: Perfecto, el tema es que la hora es la que no me deja encontrar coincidencia en la query. Hay posiblidad de que no salga la hora? Sin hacer un split

Comment: Matias: Convierte la fecha a string y toma los 10 primeros caracteres: print(Fecha.__str__()[:10]). Es una manera